# Can't remove bundler in RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, ruby-1.9.2

I have 1.9.2 Ruby installed in RVM. When I do a gem list I get this:

```
bundler (1.1.3)
```

When I try to remove it I get:

```
gem uninstall bundler
INFO:  gem "bundler" is not installed
```

When I try to run bundle install for my app I get:

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.1) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.3)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

I have tried uninstalling 1.9.2 but that did not help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer in another Stack thread but closed it without noting the link. The issue is that rvm will not let you uninstall gems from a custom gemset that are still a part of the default "global" gemset. Do a `rvm gemset use global` then uninstall 1.1.3 from global.

Comment: Awesome! :D  Should I leave it on global for my gemset?

Answer (score 0):

Running 'sudo gem uninstall' did the trick for me. It seems that 'gem uninstall' will sometimes "lie" when not running as sudo.